# Merging 2 tables and send data from 2nd table as an ArrayList

Tags: join, asp.net-core-2.0

I have to join 2 tables using lambda.

Below is the query in SQL:

```
Select 
        BD.Title
        , BD.PageUrl
        , BD.MetaDescription
        , BD.PageDescription
        , BD.Id
        , BID.BlogId
        , BID.ImageUrl

        from BlogDomain BD WITH(NOLOCK)
        left Join BlogImageDomain BID WITH(NOLOCK) ON BD.Id = BID.BlogId
        where BD.IsActive = 1
```

I have another table which has BlogId and ImageUrl which need to be mapped to the BlogDomain table. [image]

What I need to do here is that there can be a number of Image URL but they need to be mapped to the BlogDomain table according to the ID. Eg: if BlogDomain.Id is 4 then BlogImageDomain.ImageUrl **(with BlogID 4)** should show the imageURL as an array in respect to the ID

I have to add the ImageUrl as an ArrayList to show the same with the Particular Blog.

```
public class BlogDomain : BaseEntity
{
    public int BlogId{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PageDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PageHtml { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BlogProfileImage { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //public string OtherImages { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogImageDomain BlogImageDomain { get; set; }
}



public class BlogImageDomain : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

}



public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created_At { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated_At { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected class type for your result? Do you need linq query for your sql query?

Comment: @TaoZhou I need LINQ query or a Lambda query to get the result.

Comment: What is the model defination for `BlogDomain` and `BlogImageDomain`?